# Report results of scales with an unusual range

Tags: reporting

I have a questionnaire based instrument resulting in a "score" value ranged between 1 and 28. So each of my subjects/cases can have a results between 1 and 28.

The problem is: This range "feels unusual" and hard to understand on an emotional level. I can not grasp the result.

For example it is much easier to understand values in percent range from 1 to 100.

How can I help the readers (as scientists) of my scientific report to understand ("feel") the values?

My first suggestion was to transform the values on a 100-point-scale. But the results feel wired also.
The second suggestion was to use graphical bars (or lines) so they can see the range and the value as a point/line/cross on that bar.

Background:
The instrument is the [Technology Usage Inventory](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Oswald_D_Kothgassner/publication/259292979_Technology_Usage_Inventory_TUI_Manual/links/55efe54d08aedecb68fdd000.pdf) by Kothgassner et al.
The inventory includes multiple constructs/scales all with its own score value (some from 1 to 28, some from 1 to 21, one from 1 to 300). There is no summary score for the whole inventory.

Comment: Numerically 0.60714286 for example (rounded or not) is not going to be easier for most readers than the equivalent, here 17/28. The scale is what it is. Graphically your reference points are more likely to be e.g. mean or median scores than any particular level -- unless exceptionally there are rules or conventions about threshold levels.

Comment: `17/28 = 0.61` is a nice idea I think. I find it easier (but not easy) to understand.

Comment: There's no accounting for taste!